# SQL - Select days between product with the latest start date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

**Solved**

```
SELECT TO_DATE(PRODUCT_FINISH_DATE) - TO_DATE(PRODUCT_START_DATE)
FROM MANUFACTURED_PRODUCT
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY PRODUCT_START_DATE ASC;
```

-

table: `MANUFACTURED_PRODUCT`

columns: `PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_START_DATE, PRODUCT_FINISH_DATE`

SS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jj6t.png

**Attempt 1:**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(D, PRODUCT_START_DATE, PRODUCT_FINISH_DATE) as Difference
FROM MANUFACTURED_PRODUCT
ORDER BY PRODUCT_START_DATE ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Error 1:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 32
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(D, PRODUCT_START_DATE, PRODUCT_FINISH_DATE) as Difference
FROM MANUFACTURED_PRODUCT
ORDER BY PRODUCT_START_DATE ASC;
```

Error 2:

```
ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 7
```

All the examples I see look like this:

```
select DATEDIFF(d, @start, @end)
from table
order by @start asc limit 1;
```

Comment: Please at least show us some sample data (and ideally also structure) for the `MANUFACTURED_PRODUCT` table.

Comment: you have tagged your question as a `mysql` question but you are showing us oracle errors. AFAIK oracle doesn't support `LIMIT`  and `DateDiff`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
select datediff(PRODUCT_START_DATE,PRODUCT_FINISH_DATE) as Difference from FROM MANUFACTURED_PRODUCT
ORDER BY PRODUCT_START_DATE ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you have tagged your question as a `mysql` question, you are running your queries against an `oracle` database which does not support `LIMIT` and `DateDiff`.

Your first error is because you have ended your query with the unrecognized `LIMIT` and the second error is because of the unknown function `DateDiff` .

Edit: you can use this piece of code:

```
 select * from  (SELECT TO_DATE(PRODUCT_FINISH_DATE) - TO_DATE(PRODUCT_START_DATE) FROM MANUFACTURED_PRODUCT ORDER BY PRODUCT_START_DATE ASC) where rownum=1;
```

Comment: so I tried this but how do I limit the dates to just the most recent? I finally got it to work with: SELECT TO_DATE(PRODUCT_FINISH_DATE) - TO_DATE(PRODUCT_START_DATE)
FROM MANUFACTURED_PRODUCT
ORDER BY PRODUCT_START_DATE ASC;

Comment: The reason behind using a `select * from ()` is that you want to get the first row after ordering. Otherwise, you'll get unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

try this

SELECT TO_DATE(PRODUCT_FINISH_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy')-TO_DATE(PRODUCT_START_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') DAYS FROM MANUFACTURED_PRODUCT WHERE ROWNUM = 1 
ORDER BY PRODUCT_START_DATE ;